# Reusing same View/Fragment again and again

Tags: android, android-fragments, chat

every messaging app have a View
(Emoji view) at the bottom of chatting screen. As this view always remains same, I think it is complete waste to draw/render this view every time someone comes in the chatting screen. Is it possible that I draw/render this view once and use it as many times as I want without redrawing, without variables allocation without any extra stuff related to this View?

If I use fragment for this view then the fragment always gets created whenever I go to chatting screen.

What approach should I use to do this? And How to implement that approach?﻿

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you implement the parent fragment or activity.

If you've something called `ChatActivity` then you'll have a layout that's something like:

```xml
<LinearLayout>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fl"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"/>
  <fragment name=".EmojiFragment" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Within R.id.fl you inflate any "screen" that differs where .EmojiFragment always stands there.

Comment: If I will go back to previous activity and come back again to this ChatActivity, then the fragment will be drawn again. Hence, it doesn't solves my problem

Comment: You need to have a single activity handlong The whole App. Otherwise this approach wont work.

Comment: Is this good approach to use just one activity and so many fragments?

Comment: It depends on your app. I try to do as less activities as I can. Usually have no more than 2 even for big apps.